# Ошибка в yii2 при вставке во view checkbox yii2

Tags: php, yii2, checkbox

```
 <? $form->field($model, 'checkboxList')
        ->checkboxList([
        'a' => 'Элемент А',
        'б' => 'Элемент Б',
        'в' => 'Элемент В',
        ])
        ?>
```

Вставляю этот код и выдает ошибку
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Call to a member function field() on null

Это же по идее встроенная функция,так почему ошибка?

Comment: Вообще чтобы этот checkboxList отобразился на экране, нужно перед `$form` указать `echo` в данном случае код верный. Либо у Вас в модели `$model` нет атрибута `checkboxList`, либо ошибка относится к другому участку кода.

Comment: А в переменной $form действительно объект ActiveForm?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке у вас не определена переменная $form.
Убедитесь в наличии кода что-то вроде:

```
<? $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'some-form',
]); ?>
```

И, как подсказали вам в комментариях выше, поле надо вывести, а не просто создать :)

```
<?=$form->field...
```

либо

```
<? echo $form->field...
```